# ASP.NET Core WebApp(.NET Core) missing DataAnnotations

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

**Following situation:**
I have a .sln with multiple projects (data-access, business-objects, business-logic, web-server). 
The Web-Project is an ASP.NET Core Web Application using .Net-Core 1.1 with the individual user account authorization (Identity) and the "WebApplication"-Template. 
The rest of the projects is using the .Net-Framework 4.6.2.

Now I am about to remove the DBContext from the web-server and instead use the same as in the data-access-project. 
I set up my ApplicationDBContext accordingly and my User entity extends the IdentityUser. I also changed everything in the web-server-project to use the ApplicationDBContext (in my case called WTHListModell). 
I also has the references to the projects WTHList.GO (business-objects) and WTHList.DZ (data-access).

**Now here comes the problem:** 
Doing this using the full .NET-Framework for the Web-Server (creating a ".NET-Core Web-Application (.Net-Framework)" ) is successful and works just fine. 
With .Net-Core 1.1 I am getting a FileNotFound-Exception regarding "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" whenever I try to either log-in or register a user.
Now I have read, that DataAnnotations isn't compatible with .Net-Core and I also tried to add other NuGet-Packages and Assemblies to the Web-Project.

I don't know what else I can do about that, because I am supposed to use the .NET-Core Framework 1.1 for the Web-Projekt and it keeps on giving me this particular error.

**Has anybody got a clue on how to solve this issue?** 
I have searched for a while now and I haven't found a solution for this yet...

And if it has any relevance: I am using the VS2017 Enterprise RC.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
This is the content of the csproj file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-WTHList.Web2-ab5b6dbd-698d-4877-a2b3-6dd9b7a37960</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader" Version="14.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WTHList.DZ\WTHList.DZ.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WTHList.GL\WTHList.GL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WTHList.GO\WTHList.GO.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Post your csproj file content as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be confused with different "Core" terms: `.NET Core` is new "base" framework, which "looks like" `.NET Framework 4.5` (4.6, etc), but this is **other** framework. You can compile multiple versions of same project (for different frameworks) at once.

`ASP.NET Core` is like old `ASP.NET`, but a new one. It is [compiled twice](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) - once for `.NET Framework 4.5.1` (and "compatible" 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1) and once for `.NET Core` (actually, for `netstandart1.6` which is some kind of "specification", which is implemented by `NET Core`).

So, you can create web apps using `ASP.NET Core` which can build/run on `.NET Framework 4.5.1` and/or on `.NET Core`. But you need all dependencies to be also build on (compatible with) `.NET Framework 4.5.1` and/or on `.NET Core`.

So, if your app require some libraries (e.g. `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`) which is not available for `NET Core` - you can't build/run app on `.NET Core`. You can only build `ASP.NET Core` app on top of `.NET Framework 4.5.1+`.